# Is LoadRunner 9.1 support WPF?

Tags: loadrunner, mscorlib

I have POC test to clearify is LoadRunner support WPF or not? Now it can run POC thought business but it have error with some type that locate in mscorlib.dll.

I want to know how can I add reference of mscorlib.dll to LoadRunner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After POC with HP, LoadRunner 9.1 not support WPF and some aspect of .NET 3.5 feature.

Answer (score 1):

lr_load_dll() for loading your DLL.   Make sure it is thread safe at the client level for multiple use.

Second issue, WPF.   Take a look at the advanced section of the VUGEN users guide, specifcally the section on building virtual users with C/C++ or VB in Visual Studio.   Even if your particular communication variant is not supported you often can leverage your source code in a DLL style virtual user to get the job done.